# Singleton send signal to actual running process

Tags: python

I've developed a program in Python and pyGtk and today added the singleton feature, which doesn't allow to run it if it is already running. But now I want to go further and, if its running, *somehow* make it call self.window.present() to showit.

So I've been looking at Signals, PIPE, FIFO, MQ, Socket, etc. for three hours now! I don't know if I'm just not seeing it or what, but can't find the way to do this (even when lots of apps do it)

Now, the question would be: How do I send a "signal" to a running instance of the same script (which is not in an infinite bucle listening for it, but doing it's job), to make it call a function?

I'm trying sending signals, using:

```
os.kill(int(apid[0]),signal.SIGUSR1)
```

and receiving them with:

```
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, self.handler)

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
```

but it kills the running process with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./algest_new.py", line 4080, in <module>
    gtk.main()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: A linux-only solution would be to use `os.mkfifo` to communicate between processes.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, you don't. When you say you have implemented a "singleton feature" I'm not sure exactly what you mean. It seems almost as though you are expecting the code in the second process to be able to see the singleton object in the first one, which clearly isn't possible. But I may have misunderstood.

The usual way to do this is to create a file with a unique name at a known location, typically containing the process id of the running process. If you start your program and it sees the file already present it knows to explain to the user that there's a copy already running. You could also send a signal to that process (under Unix, anyway) to tell it to bring its window to the foreground.

Oh, and don't forget that your program should delete the PIDfile when it terminates :-)

Comment: "You could also send a signal to that process", that's what I'm trying to do now. I'm trying with kill but it kills the running app, I'm missing something and don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, `gtk.main` will raise the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception if the signal handler raises any exception.  With this program:

```
import gtk
import signal

def ohno(*args):
    raise Exception("Oh no")

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, ohno)

gtk.main()
```

After launching, calling `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)` from another process results in this exception:

```
  File "signaltest.py", line 9, in <module>
    gtk.main()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

This seems to be an issue with pygtk - an exception raised by a `signal.signal` handler in a non-gtk python app will do the expected thing and display the handler's exception (e.g. "Oh no").

So in short: if `gtk.main` is raising `KeyboardInterrupt` in response to other signals, check that your signal handlers aren't raising exceptions of their own.